# Nested sampling: What does "uniform sampling over the prior" mean?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, likelihood, prior

I'm reading up on Nested Sampling in the book "Data Analysis - A Bayesian Tutorial" (Sivia and Skilling, 2006), and I do not understand the following:

**What I understand:**

Given a prior $\pi(\mathbf{x})$ and a likelihood $L(\mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^N$ are the parameters of a model, we want to compute
$$Z=\int L(\mathbf{x})\pi(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}.$$

For that, we define the function
$$\xi(\lambda)=\int_{L(\mathbf{x})>\lambda}\pi(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}$$
which is the proportion of prior with likelihood greater than $\lambda$.

It is argued that there is one-to-one correspondence between $\xi$ and $\mathbf{x}$.

**What I don't understand:**

Nested sampling is explained as follows:

"[...] [Nested sampling] uses a collection of $n$ objects, randomly sampled with respect to the prior $\pi$, but also subject to an evolving constraint $L(x) > L^∗$ preventing the likelihood from exceeding the current limiting value $L^∗$. [...] In terms of $\xi$, the objects are uniformly sampled subject to the constraint $\xi$<$\xi^*$, where $\xi^*$ corresponds to $L^∗$."

**My question:**

- Why does sampling from $\pi(\mathbf{x})$ correspond to uniform sampling in $\xi\in [0,1]$?
- What is meant by "uniform sampling from $\pi(\mathbf{x})$"? (How can sampling from a non-uniform distribution be uniform?)

Answer (score 1):

**Why does sampling from π(x) correspond to uniform sampling in ξ∈[0,1]?**

When you sample from the prior, and evaluate the likelihood, you are sampling also a distribution of likelihoods. In the beginning, considering the unconstrained prior, the likelihoods are not limited (-inf,+inf).

Picking a likelihood from the sampled likelihoods cuts the prior according to the quantile where that likelihood lies. So if you pick the 10% quantile likelihood $\lambda_{0.1}$ from your sampled values, and restrict the prior to likelihoods above $\lambda_{0.1}$, then you are limiting the prior volume by 10%.

Maybe this text is helpful: https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.15570

**What is meant by "uniform sampling from π(x)"? (How can sampling from a non-uniform distribution be uniform?)**

What is meant here is faithfully sampling from π(x). Some sampling techniques may have issues (for example, generating points with Metropolis random walks with too short length or poorly constructed transition kernels). Here it is assumed that this is solved and glanced over to focus on fundamental properties.